# Not able to call a method outside render from a function inside render

Tags: reactjs

```
class TableView extends React.Component {  
    state = {
        open: false,
    };

    onOpenModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    onCloseModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    render() {
        function showHistory() {
            this.onOpenModal; // not able to do this
            console.log(this.state.open); // or this
        }
        return (
             //...
             //...
            <Modal open={this.state.open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
                <h2>History</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
                    pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis. Pellentesque sit amet
                    hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
                </p>
            </Modal>
       );
   }
}
```

I am able to hit showHistory method on click of a button inside a jsx. But,when I try to call onOpenModal from showHistory, it throws error -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onOpenModal' of undefined

How do I call onOpenModal from showhistory ?

Comment: it means you donot have this available. Instead use arrow function inside render

Comment: why are you adding this function within render? this isn't the normal place for functions in react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are not calling `onOpenModal`, you are missing the parenthesis: `this.onOpenModal()` secondly you have to bind `showHistory` to `this`.
Hope it helps:

```js
class TableView extends React.Component {  
    state = {
        open: false,
    };

    onOpenModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    onCloseModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    render() {
        function showHistory() {
            this.onOpenModal(); // not able to do this
            console.log(this.state.open); // or this
        }.bind(this);
        return (
             //...
             //...
       );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, you might just need the parenthesis

`this.onOpenModal()`

failing that move the function outside of the render

```
class TableView extends React.Component {  
    state = {
        open: false,
    };

    onOpenModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    onCloseModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    showHistory() {
        () => this.onOpenModal() // not able to do this
        console.log(this.state.open); // or this
    }

    render() {
        return (
             //...
             //...
            <Modal open={this.state.open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
                <h2>History</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
                    pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis. Pellentesque sit amet
                    hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
                </p>
            </Modal>
       );
     }
   }
```

it could be that you need to bind `this`, the simplest way to do this is using fat arrow functions

`() => this.onOpenModal()`

Comment: even fat arrow function?

Comment: after adding fat arrow, this did not give any error but its not hitting onOpenModal() either.

Comment: did you move the function outside of render?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the method in the constructor or you can bind it when it is called,

```
 class TableView extends React.Component { 
       constructor(props){
       this.state = {
            open: false,
        };
       this.onOpenModal = this.onOpenModal.bind(this)
       this.onCloseModal = this.onCloseModal.bind(this)
         } 
        onOpenModal = () => {
            this.setState({ open: true });
        };

        onCloseModal = () => {
            this.setState({ open: false });
        };

        render() {
            function showHistory() {
                this.onOpenModal; // not able to do this
                console.log(this.state.open); // or this
            }
            return (
                 //...
                 //...
                <Modal open={this.state.open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
                    <h2>History</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
                        pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis. Pellentesque sit amet
                        hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
                    </p>
                </Modal>
           );
       }
    }
```

Also please note ,
In your case ,state declared as a class properties and not an instance property.

```
 state = {} //class property will not available on this object
```

Either do state declaraion in constructor

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {};   // now state available on this object
}
```

or remove this when referring state.It is better to declare state in constructor as you are using the method `this.setState`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to define function inside render if its possible to define at **class/component** level.

Within **class/component**,you can place it parallel to render.

```
showHistory = ()=> {
    this.onOpenModal(); // not able to do this
    console.log(this.state.open); // or this
}
```

Or
if you want to go with same code placing,defined inside render using arrow function

```
const showHistory = () =>{
            this.onOpenModal; // not able to do this
            console.log(this.state.open); // or this
        }
```

And from html invoke it like this `showHistory()`